# How to select queries for text search benchmark?

Tags: algorithm, performance, full-text-search

I have written a text search (exact text search) algorithm which I now want to evaluate.
I had a look at two research papers in that topic, but I didn't find the exact way they choose the pattern to search for.

I found *The Canterbury Corpus*, which is used for benchmarking. I appreciate other suggestions.
How to select the patterns/queries to search for?
Selection by hand seems tedious, I could generate random numbers, interpret as index and take a substring starting at the index.

Are there other/better ways to do this?

Comment: If you had any real application in mind while designing the algorithm, real queries would be the best test-queries. Make sure you also have queries with **no match** in your text

Comment: I think searching for full words (or word-tuples) of a dictionary could be a god approach. Random snippets are i real live only common when searching in binary data.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the BEIR project for benchmarking: https://github.com/beir-cellar/beir

This goes into more detail in the types of tests you can run. And I believe one of the most popular datasets for evaluations is MS Marco: https://microsoft.github.io/msmarco/
They have some clearly defined retrieval tasks you can adapt for your case.

There's a leaderboard available for the best ranking search engines, so it can give you some idea of where you stand.

Hope this helps!